# displaying local storage values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage

I am trying to display only the values which are saved inside of the local storage and not the key value which will show all the data in the local storage after the login form has been submitted

```
    welcome <span id="demo"></span>
        <script>

     document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=localStorage.getItem ("users") === ("username");

  </script>
```

Comment: can you please show the value of `users` in your localStorage? and maybe give an example of what data exactly do you wanna show?

Comment: [{"username":"IB365rrrrr","email":"bajada1989@gmail.com","password":"hjh"}, the username i want to display not all of the users info

Comment: `var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.users), name = obj.username;`

Comment: `console.log(typeof localStorage.getItem ("users"))`

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
let userData = localStorage.getItem ("users") ;
if(userData) {
    userData = JSON.parse(userData);
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = userData[0]['username'];
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: it worked but how can i change the user name each time a different user presses the submit button in the login form? thanks man :)

Comment: The `localStorage` is unique for each browser, For all user "if they are using different pc". then the localstorage value will be based on the user. The localstorage store data on client side.

Comment: ye i know but with the [0]  only the 1st user will be displayed

Comment: One thing to note that the localstorage is not shared with different browsers. To answer you question. you can loop the `userData` variable and print it on screen.` userData.forEach(element => {
                console.log(element.username);
            });`

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all, you really should not save the password in your `localStorage`.

The `user` (Not `users`) should be an object that is holding ONLY public information that you don't mind even other websites to have access to.

And it should be something like `{username: "Something", email: "something@tada.com"}`

By that you can use it like this:

```
let user = localStorage.getItem('user');
if (user) {
    user = JSON.parse(user);
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = user.username;
}
```